# ¿Cómo actualizar una columna de una tabla por otra agregando un texto en SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Quiero actualizar un campo password por un texto mas el dato que viene en una columna de fecha, pero no he podido lograrlo, tengo una idea pero no me ejecuta, claro es la sintaxis, alguien tite alguna idea de como seria, Gracias por el apoyo.

Código SQL

```
UPDATE usuarios SET usuarios.password='F45'+empleados.fec_baj
FROM usuarios 
INNER JOIN empleados empleados ON usuarios.usuario=empleados.emp
```

El texto seria f45 mas la fecha_baj

Lo que quiero obtener seria F4514/12/2002

Comment: Y... cuál es el mensaje de error?

Comment: ¿Por qué estás guardando contraseñas en texto plano? Las contraseñas deben estar encriptadas de forma que no se puedan recuperar. Ese es un riesgo enorme de seguridad.

Comment: ¿Es MySQL o SQL Server? Has etiquetado las dos y la sintaxis es diferente

Answer (score 0):

Puedes calcular el nuevo password con una subconsulta:

```
UPDATE usuarios u SET u.password = CONCAT("F45", (SELECT e.fec_baj FROM empleados e WHERE e.emp = u.usuario LIMIT 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Para SQL Server tu consulta estaba bastante cerca de lo que necesitas:

```
UPDATE usuarios 
SET password='F45' + convert(varchar, empleados.fecha_baj, 3)
FROM usuarios INNER JOIN empleados  
ON usuarios.usuario=empleados.emp
```

Y te dejo un DBFiddle para que puedas jugar con la consulta: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0aff38461aa0a992eb6747b48a14a117

Notas:

- Unes por el campo usuarios.usuario y empleados.emp. ¿Es lo mismo el usuario que el empleado? ¿son campos clave de tipo int? Si es el nombre, puedes tener un fallo de diseño ahí.
- Jamás, jamás, nunca jamás, guardes así tus contraseñas en producción. Siempre encriptadas.